# Getting uncaught Type Error: Cannot read properties of null on addEventListener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm making a button which changes the theme on click, but on adding event listener I'm getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') at theme.js:27:13` , can you guys take a look at my code and tell me what am I doing wrong.

Here's the code:

```
const /*nodeelement*/ $HTML = document.documentElement;
const /*boolean*/ isDark = window.matchMedia(
    "(prefers-color-scheme:dark)"
  ).matches;

if (sessionStorage.getItem("theme")) {
  $HTML.dataset.theme = sessionStorage.getItem("theme");
} else {
  $HTML.dataset.theme = isDark ? "dark" : "light";
}

// function to change the theme bw light and dark
let isPressed = false;

const changeTheme = function () {
  isPressed = isPressed ? false : true;
  this.setAttribute("aria-pressed", isPressed);
  $HTML.setAttribute(
    "data-theme",
    $HTML.dataset.theme === "light" ? "dark" : "light"
  );
  sessionStorage.setItem("theme", $HTML.dataset.theme);
};

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  const $themeBtn = document.querySelector("[data-theme-btn]");
  $themeBtn.addEventListener("click", changeTheme);
});
```

I have tried doing everything like putting my scripts tag at the end of the body but it's not working, So please could anyone of you can help fix this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The query selector isn't finding the button. Are you sure it's in the HTML, not added dynamically later?

Comment: If you read the error its saying you are attaching `addEventListener` to a null item. The rest of the code isn't needed to solve the problem. Now since window isn't null that means `$themeBtn` is null. You haven't shown us the HTML which would show the button